# Juego de Picas y Fijas

Tags: python

Lo que pasa es que me pidieron un juego de Picas y Fijas utilizando diccionarios pero al momento de hacerlo solo se suman las PICAS y no las FIJAS o me las cuenta al revés.

El juego de las Picas y Fijas consiste en adivinar un número de 4 cifras y de todos los dígitos diferentes. Para esto, el jugador que intenta adivinar deberá decir el número que cree está escondiendo el otro, y este deberá responder el número de picas y fijas que tiene ahora el jugador.

- Una **pica** es un dígito que se encuentra en el número a adivinar, pero no está en el lugar correcto
- Una **fija** es un dígito correctamente colocado

Entonces, quisiera que me ayudaran o si me podrían decir mis errores o como se podría hacer para realizarlo ojala me contesten y no eliminen mi pregunta jajajajajaja, de antemano muchas gracias. Espero me puedan ayudar.

```py
    def picas_y_fijas(numero_secreto: int, intento: int) -> dict:
        diccionario = {"PICAS": 0, "FIJAS": 0}
        a = intento % 10
        intento = intento // 10
        b = intento % 10
        intento = intento // 10
        c = intento % 10
        intento = intento // 10
        d = intento % 10
        intento = intento // 10
        if str(a) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 == intento % 10:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 0
        if str(a) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 != intento % 10:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 0
        numero_secreto = numero_secreto // 10
        intento = intento // 10
        if str(b) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 == intento % 10:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 0
        if str(b) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 != intento % 10:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 0
        numero_secreto = numero_secreto // 10
        intento = intento // 10
        if str(c) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 == intento % 10:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 0
        if str(c) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 != intento % 10:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 0
        numero_secreto = numero_secreto // 10
        intento = intento // 10
        if str(d) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 == intento % 10:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 0
        if str(d) in str(numero_secreto) and numero_secreto % 10 != intento % 10:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 1
        else:
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 0
        numero_secreto = numero_secreto // 10
        intento = intento // 10
        return diccionario
```

Comment: ¿En qué consiste el juego de picas y fijas?

Comment: Revisa por favor la indentación del código. La línea del `def` está a la misma altura que el resto. La forma más sencilla de pegar código con la indentación correcta es ponerle una línea con ``` al inicio y otra al final para delimitarlo y que stackoverflow lo muestre como código respetando la indentación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lo que escribiste estas tratando de resolver el problema manualmente. Esto hace que el código sea redundante, largo y difícil de mantener. Debes abstraer el problema y luego implementarlo usando las herramientas que te ofrecen los lenguajes.

Se me ocurre hacer una función que diga cuantas *picas* y *fijas* tiene cada intento. En esta función se va procesando la última cifra y se va eliminando por cada vuelta del `while` hasta que `intento = 0`.

```
def picas_y_fijas(numero_secreto: int, intento: int) -> dict:
    diccionario = {"PICAS": 0, "FIJAS": 0}
    num_ref = numero_secreto
    while intento > 0:
        i = num_ref % 10 # ultima cifra
        j = intento % 10 # ultima cifra
        if i == j:
            diccionario["FIJAS"] += 1
        elif str(j) in str(numero_secreto):
            diccionario["PICAS"] += 1
        num_ref = num_ref // 10 # Se elimina la ultima cifra
        intento = intento // 10 # idem
    return diccionario
```

Edit: Observé en un juego online que si una cifra cae en `FIJAS`, ya no cuenta en `PICAS`. Para que esto sea así, entonces queda en un bloque `if - elif`.

Ahora si, si le mandamos datos de ejemplo a esa función:

```
print(picas_y_fijas(356, 485)) # Da: {'PICAS': 1, 'FIJAS': 0}
print(picas_y_fijas(365, 359)) # Da: {'PICAS': 1, 'FIJAS': 1}
print(picas_y_fijas(356, 356)) # Da: {'PICAS': 0, 'FIJAS': 3}
print(picas_y_fijas(356, 980)) # Da: {'PICAS': 0, 'FIJAS': 0}
print(picas_y_fijas(3568, 9801)) # Da: {'PICAS': 1, 'FIJAS': 0}
```

Ahora solo tienes que hacer un programa principal, donde controlas la cantidad de intentos, obviamente usando bucles `for` o `while`.
Adicional debes controlar que el usuario no meta un número con cifras repetidas, ni que tu programa genere un `numero_secreto` con cifras repetidas.
Para saber si la persona ganó, pues `numero_secreto == intento`

Answer (score 0):

también puedes implementar un ciclo "for in", el cual facilita un poco más a la hora de escribir tu código. La única diferencia que tiene es que tendrás que convertir primero tus números a "string"

```
def picas_y_fijas(numero_secreto,intento: int) -> dict:
    res={"PICAS":0 , "FIJAS":0 }
    numero_secreto=str(numero_secreto)
    intento=str(intento)
    for i in range(0,len(numero_secreto)):
        if intento[i]==numero_secreto[i]:
            res["FIJAS"]+=1
        elif intento[i] in numero_secreto:
            res["PICAS"]+=1
    return res
```